# Is it possible for integer division in C++ to express a compact mathematical condition, as for Euclidean division?

Tags: arithmetic, euclidean-algorithm, programming

I am studying [integer division](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) in C++. At the same time, I read the wikipedia article '[Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division)'. In this article there is such a lemma:

```
a = b · q + r     // formula
0 ≤ r < |b|       // condition
```

In these formulas `a` — dividend, `b` — divisor (`b ≠ 0`), `q` — quotient and `r` — remainder.

As far as I understand, the condition `0 ≤ r < |b|` is necessary to ensure the unambiguity of the division results.

I compared the results of some examples of integer division for Euclidean division and for integer division in C++. They work in different ways:

```
 a  | b  | Euclidean division|       in C++      | matching
    |    |  a / b  |  a % b  |  a / b  |  a % b  | results
----------------------------------------------------------------
 13 |  5 |    2    |    3    |    2    |    3    |    yes
-13 |  5 |   -3    |    2    |   -2    |   -3    |    no
 13 | -5 |   -2    |    3    |   -2    |    3    |    yes
-13 | -5 |    3    |    2    |    2    |   -3    |    no
```

Notation in the table: `a / b` equivalent to quotient `q`, `a % b` equivalent to remainder `r`.

I understand how integer division works in C++:

1. `q` (quotient) is obtained by cutting off (truncate) the fractional part from the result of the usual division `a / b`;
2. the sign of the quotient `q` is obtained as in the usual division;
3. the sign of the remainder `r` is obtained by deducing from the formula (mnemonic: the sign is the same as that of the dividend `a`; [this has been added since C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13100805/16458042), before the remainder sign was implementation-defined).

**My question.** Is it possible for integer division in C++ to express the above verbal description with a compact mathematical condition, as for Euclidean division? What might it look like?

```
a = b · q + r     // formula
???               // condition
```

Comment: If the operands are negative the sign of the remainder used to be implementation-defined, so not part of the c++ standard. You should not rely on it because it can vary between compilers. In your case it looks like the condition is that $a$ and $r$ have the same sign.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek You write `the sign of the remainder used to be implementation-defined, so not part of the c++ standard`. It seems to have been [removed, starting with C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13100805/16458042). Now, according to the C++ standard, the sign of the remainder coincides with the sign of the dividend.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek You write `In your case it looks like the condition is that _a_
 and _r_ have the same sign.` No, this does not eliminate ambiguity when finding the quotient and remainder. For example, with integer division `-13 / 5`, we can say that `q=-2` and `r=-3` (in C++), and we can say that `q=-1` and `r=-8` (the condition you proposed is satisfied, but there are still several solutions, not one).

Comment: Then add $|r|<|b|$ still.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Maybe this will do. As I understand it, you are offering two conditions at the same time. But you expressed the first condition in words. How can the condition about the sign of the remainder be expressed mathematically? Is it possible to write `sgn a = sgn r`, where `sgn` is a [signum function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function)?

Comment: If you insist then yes. Or $ar\geq 0$.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Could you write your suggestion in the answer to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most similar way to express similar to the Euclidean division i believe would be

$$
a = b \cdot q + r
\\
0 \le \mathrm{sgn}(a) r < |b|
$$

Proof:

We can let the original Euclidean divide do all the proving by considering the two cases:

1. When $a>0$ then the original Euclidean division form is retained
   $$
   a = b \cdot q + r
   \\
   0 \le r < |b|
   $$
2. Otherwise $a<0$ then rewrite the system as
   $$
   a' = b \cdot q' + r'
   \\
   0 \le r' < |b|
   $$
   where
   $$
   a'=-a\\
   q'=-q\\
   r'=-r
   $$

This not only proves the uniqueness of the solution, but also shows how the values could be computed from the Euclidean division. For $a > 0$ results are identical.

Example: Given $a = -13$, $b = 5$, then $a'=13$. Euclidean division gives the solution $q'=2$ and $r'=3$. Thus $q=-2$ and $r=-3$.

Example 2: Given $a = -13$, $b = -5$, then $a'=13$. Euclidian division gives the solution $q'=-2$ and $r'=3$. Thus $q=2$ and $r=-3$.

---

Edit: Having re-read the question more carefully, I now realize I initially misunderstood what was requested (sorry). I will just leave the code as is in case anyone who wants to compute the Euclidean division might stumble on it.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>


template<typename T>
std::tuple<T, T> euclidean_divide(T dividend, T divisor) {
    if (dividend >= 0) {
        return {dividend / divisor, dividend % divisor};
    } else {
        dividend = std::abs(dividend);
        if (divisor > 0) {
            return {-((dividend + divisor) / divisor), divisor - (dividend % divisor)};
        } else {
            divisor = std::abs(divisor);
            return {(dividend + divisor) / divisor, divisor - (dividend % divisor)};
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    auto [q0, r0] = euclidean_divide(13, 5);
    std::cout << q0 << ',' << r0 << std::endl;
    auto [q1, r1] = euclidean_divide(-13, 5);
    std::cout << q1 << ',' << r1 << std::endl;
    auto [q2, r2] = euclidean_divide(13, -5);
    std::cout << q2 << ',' << r2 << std::endl;
    auto [q3, r3] = euclidean_divide(-13, -5);
    std::cout << q3 << ',' << r3 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I like your version, it is very similar to the Euclidean division condition. (Your version is probably derived from there?) Do I understand correctly that two inequalities `ar≥0; |r|<|b|` (suggested by @MichalAdamaszek) are the equivalent of your inequality (but your version is more compact, this is an advantage)?

Comment: Can you add at least short thoughts about the proof of the lemma in your version? Is it possible to use the [Division theorem proof from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division#Proof) (after all, your inequality differs little from the original one)?

Comment: @IlyaChalov Sorry for delay, on a trip. I added a proof, though i just rely on the original proof for all the heavy lifting. Yes the two inequalities in the comments would give the same condition.

Comment: Thanks for adding! Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to vote for your answer and comment.